# Sorting a view on a taxonomy term with entityqueue

Tags: views, queue

I'm trying to use an entity queue on a taxonomy to create a new sort order for an existing view. But I'm having trouble configuring it.

I've created a dummy website with a fantasy role-playing game theme. I have a content type "Monster" with a taxonomy term "difficulty".

[image]

Monsters can have several difficulty tags, but I've created an entityqueue for the subset of tags that I want to sort on:

[image]

Finally, I've created the view for monsters, with what I believe are the properly relationships to join in the entityqueue for sorting. Starting with the Monster content type, I've added a relationship to the Difficulty taxonomy term, then another relationship for the Monster Difficulty entityqueue.
[image]

Finally, I added the entityqueue as the first sort criteria:

[image]

However, the results of the view are still sorting on the title field, "Name", meaning that the sort order of the entityqueue is either not making it in or being respected:

[image]

How do I sort a view based on a taxonomy entityqueue?

**Edit** I removed the sort for the title, as per hotwebmatter's suggestion, but that didn't cause it to sort by the entityqueue.

[image]

The order should go Big boss, boss, mini-boss, etc., but it doesn't.

[image]

Here are the configuration export ymls of those files different from a vanilla install: https://pastebin.com/r4A94QJ5

Comment: Did you remove “Content: Title (asc)” from the Sort Criteria? Did it work?

Comment: @hotwebmatter I tried that, it did not. See question edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the **Queue Position** sort is being overridden by the **Title** sort. (In other words, the **Title** sort may be applied *after* the **Taxonomy term Queue Position** sort, making it appear as though the queue is not respected.)

If that's the case, then removing the **Title** field from the Sort criteria should be enough to get this working.

In case that's not sufficient, here's a [good video tutorial on Entityqueue](https://gogrow.org/tutorials/entityqueue).

Comment: First time I hear of this module. Watching the video looks like it does the same as the **[weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/weight)** module, which allows you to re-order your View's rows to your liking.

Comment: Althought the advantage of this module is that it allows you to create various Queues while the weight module you're stuck with the same weight config.

Comment: @NoSssweat Entityqueue is a rewrite of Nodequeue. These modules are great for giving clients the ability to reorder intent to their liking, without necessarily even having granting them a content editor role. (A user may be granted permission to reorder a queue of content  without the ability to edit that content.)

Comment: There’s also another similar module called Draggable Views (http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) but off the top of my head I’m not sure of the pros and cons of the four different modules.

Comment: https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/drupal-7-when-use-entityqueue-vs-draggable-views